# Socket java client-server

Tags: java, sockets

I have to build a server and a client in Java. The server opens a connection on port 18163. The client connects to the server and establishes a number X, the server sends the message "guess", the server received the message repeatedly attempts to determine the value of X to the client sending the message "I feel Y" where Y is the value of a integer. When the client receives the message "I feel Y" sends to the server: "Same" if the number is correct, "Not equal if the number is not correct." If the number is correct, the server sends the client the "Close" and the client closes the connection.

I have to implement this program without the use of thread! I tried that, but it doesn't work.

CLIENT:

```
public class Client{

  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{

    Socket c= new Socket("127.0.0.1",18163);

    BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream()));
    DataOutputStream outToServer=new DataOutputStream(c.getOutputStream());

    int min=1,max=10;
    String frase;
    int n1;


    int numcasuale=(min+(int)(Math.random()*((max - min)+1)));

     System.out.println("Num casuale generato: "+numcasuale);




               do{
            frase=inFromServer.readLine();
                   n1=Integer.parseInt(frase);

                   System.out.println("DAL SERVER: PROVO "+n1);

              }while(!(n1==numcasuale));
                    outToServer.writeBytes("UGUALE\n");
        frase=inFromServer.readLine();
         if(frase.equals("CLOSE")){ 
               System.out.println("Esecuzione terminata.");
                       c.close(); 
                       }
  }
}
```

SERVER:

```
public class Server{

  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception{
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(18163);

        int min=1,max=10,numcasuale;
        String dallclient;


        while(true){
          Socket c= ss.accept();
          System.out.println("Client connesso: "+ c.getRemoteSocketAddress()); 

          DataOutputStream alclient=new DataOutputStream(c.getOutputStream());

 BufferedReader dalclient =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream())); 

          dallclient= dalclient.readLine();



                 System.out.println("DAL CLIENT :"+dallclient);

                 do{
                   numcasuale=(min+(int)(Math.random()*((max - min)+1)));
                   alclient.write(numcasuale);
                               dallclient= dalclient.readLine();
                   System.out.println("DAL CLIENT: "+dallclient);
                  }while(!(dallclient.equals("UGUALE")));

                 }alclient.writeBytes("CLOSE\n");





  }


}
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: it looks like your client isn't doing what you say it's supposed to in the description: "When the client receives the message "I feel Y" sends to the server: "Same" if the number is correct, "Not equal if the number is not correct...." -> but your client enters a do while loop reading in a guess from the server as an int only and never responding until it's a correct guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the server part you are missing an `\n` at this line:

```
while( !(dallclient.equals("UGUALE")) );
```

since the client is sending `"UGUALE\n"`

```
outToServer.writeBytes("UGUALE\n");
```

Comment: You can format the code by placing backticks (`) around it or by placing it on a new line indented with 4 spaces.